# String to Multidimensional Array with Unique value in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unique-array

I have below string and want to create multidimensional array using unique value

```
 $string = 'test.jpg|test1.jpg|^22##29##p-test.jpg^22##29##test.video^22##30##p-test2.jpg^22##30##p-test3.jpg^22##30##test4.jpg^22##31##p-CCA_Nestea.jpg^22##31##p-test3.jpg|^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##33##p-test3.jpg|test1.jpg';
```

So I have tried below code but not working

```
$string = 'test.jpg|test1.jpg|^22##29##p-test.jpg^22##29##test.video^22##30##p-test2.jpg^22##30##p-test3.jpg^22##30##test4.jpg^22##31##p-test22.jpg^22##31##p-test3.jpg|^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##33##p-test3.jpg|test1.jpg';
$content_arr = explode("|", $string);
global $db;
$arr1 = array(); $p =0;$prev_layout ='';
foreach($content_arr as $arr){
    if(strpos($arr, '^') !== false) {           
        $l_data = explode("^",$arr);
        $larr = array();
        foreach ($l_data as $l) {
            if(strpos($l, '##') !== false) {        
                $p = explode("##",$l);

                $l_name = 'test lay';

                $p_name = 'test pame';
                if(!in_array($prev_layout,$p_arr)){
                    $p_arr = array();                   
                    $p_arr['l_id'] =$p[0];
                    $p_arr['l_name'] =$l_name;
                    $p_arr['l_interval'] ='';
                }
                $p_arr['panel'][$p++] = array('p_id'=>$p[1],'p_name'=>$p_name,'p_interval'=>'','p_element'=>$p[2]); 
                if($p_arr['layout_id'] != $p[0])
                //if(!in_array($prev_layout,$p_arr, true)){
                    array_push($arr1,$p_arr);
                //}
                if (substr($p[2], -6) != '.video') {
                    $c++;
                }
                $prev_layout = $p[0];
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

?>

OUTPUT would be

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [l_id] => 22
            [l_name] => test Menu
            [l_interval] => 
            [panel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 29
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] =>   [0] => Array
                                             (
                                             [0] => test.jpg,
                                             [1] => test1.jpg
                                             )
                        )


                )

        )
```

Comment: so you want above given output?? what about `Creative_Holidays_Bali.video` and `p-test3.jpg` and other strings???

Comment: Can you please explain the logic inside your output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and modify that is it correct According to your estimated output?

```
$string = 'test.jpg|test1.jpg|^22##29##p-test.jpg^22##29##test.video^22##30##p-test2.jpg^22##30##p-test3.jpg^22##30##test4.jpg^22##31##p-test22.jpg^22##31##p-test3.jpg|^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##32##p-test3.jpg^24##33##p-test3.jpg|test1.jpg';
$arr1 =$p_arr= array(); $p =0;$prev_layout ='';
$content_arr = array_filter(explode("|", $string));
global $db;
foreach($content_arr as $arr){
    if(strpos($arr, '^') !== false) {
        $larr = array();
        $l_data = array_filter(explode("^",$arr));
        foreach ($l_data as $l) {
            if(strpos($l, '##') !== false) {
                 $l_name = 'test lay'; $p_name = 'Left';//'test pame';
                 $p=array();
                $p = explode("##",$l); 
                $p0 = $p[0];
                $p1 = $p[1];
                unset($p[0]);unset($p[1]);
                if(!array_key_exists($p0,$p_arr)){
                    $p_arr[$p0] =   array('l_id'=>$p0,
                                          'l_name'=>$l_name,
                                          'l_interval'=>'','panel'=>array());
                }
                if(!array_key_exists($p1,$p_arr[$p0]['panel'])){
                    $p_arr[$p0]['panel'][$p1] = array('p_id'=>$p1,'p_name'=>$p_name,'p_interval'=>'','p_element'=>array(array_values($p)));
                }else{
                    $p_arr[$p0]['panel'][$p1]['p_element'][] = array_values($p);
                  //$p_arr[$p0]['panel'][$p1]['p_element'] = array_merge($p_arr[$p0]['panel'][$p1]['p_element'],array_values($p));//if you want to mearge array 
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($p_arr);die;
```

And Out put of that is

```
Array
(
    [22] => Array
        (
            [l_id] => 22
            [l_name] => test lay
            [l_interval] => 
            [panel] => Array
                (
                    [29] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 29
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test.jpg
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => test.video
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 30
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test2.jpg
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test3.jpg
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => test4.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [31] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 31
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test22.jpg
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test3.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [l_id] => 24
            [l_name] => test lay
            [l_interval] => 
            [panel] => Array
                (
                    [32] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 32
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test3.jpg
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test3.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [33] => Array
                        (
                            [p_id] => 33
                            [p_name] => Left
                            [p_interval] => 
                            [p_element] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => p-test3.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @Bhumi Shah is this Answer is Suitable your output?

Comment: no it is not proper, you can 29 have only two values.

Comment: @BhumiShah Now it according to your expected o/p. If you want to merge 'p_element' arrays then replace **'p_element'=>array(array_values($p))** to **'p_element'=>array_values($p)** and un-comment  'array_merge' line ,than make comment above line